# Data not coming in JSON format from Splunk Javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, json, search, sdk, splunk

I am querying Splunk using javascript SDK. In the searchParams, i have given the output mode as "json_rows".

```
var searchParams = {
    exec_mode: "normal",
    output_mode: "json_rows"
};
```

But still when i get the output, i don't get it in a JSON format. The output is coming as an array.

Any idea what is going wrong? I tried "json_cols" and only "json" also. Same result.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:2

Some more of the code

```
var service = new splunkjs.Service({
    username:"xxx",
    password:"xxxx",
    scheme:"https",
    host:"xxxxxx.com",
    port:"5500",
    version:"5.0"
  });

var searchQuery = 'search index=sn impact=1 OR impact=2 | eval time = round( strptime(impact_start,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 0 )| where time >= ' + 14334627 + ' AND time<=' + 14568862 + '| bucket time span=1d | stats values(number) as incident_name by time';
var searchParams = {
    exec_mode: "normal",
    output_mode: "JSON"
};
service.oneshotSearch(
    searchQuery,
    searchParams,
    function(err, results) {
        if ( results ) {
            var incidentResp = {};
            incidentResp["data"] = results.rows;
            incidentResp["error"] = null;
            callback(null, incidentResp);
            return;
        }
        else {
            var errResp = {};
            errResp["data"] = null;
            errResp["error"] =err;
            callback(null, errResp);
            return;
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but let me try to help.

output_mode just tells the REST API how to serialize and return the results, usually either JSON, XML, or CSV

Given you're using the JavaScript SDK to pull data into your application and not actually having the results written to file, I would leave this as is (JSON default)

You'll find the actual data in the 'results' of the response.

eg.

```
service.oneshotSearch( query, params,
    function(err, response) {
        if (err) throw new Error ( err );
        console.log( response.results );
});
```

Try changing this line:

```
incidentResp["data"] = results.rows;:
```

To this:

```
incidentResp["data"] = results.results;
```

... but yes, this will be an array of results.

Hope this helps